# How is "raising defences to summary judgment" an example of a contract being undermined that can be prevented with a NOM clause?

Tags: contract-law

In Rock Advertising Ltd. v. MWB Bus. Exchange Centres Ltd [2018] UK 24 Lord Sumption lists reasons why No Oral Modification clauses are beneficial.

"The first is that it prevents attempts to undermine written agreements by informal means, a possibility which is open to abuse, for example in raising defences to summary judgment." at para 12.

I do not understand the example he gives, how does this undermine a contract?

Thanks

Comment: This question may appear quite rough, but it is actually a good one. Don't jump to conclusions re lack of clarity as the references are clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say Bob and Rob have a written contract.

Bob becomes unhappy with what Rob does and sues him for breach of contract. Specifically, Bob applies for a [summary judgment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summary_judgment) because, in his view, the breach is so clear so that no hearing/trial is needed.

Rob opposes judging the case that way. This is what "defence to summary judgment" is — Rob wants a hearing. He says that the contract was modified orally, and in the light of that modification there is now no breach as Bob alleges, so we need a hearing so that his [right to natural justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_justice#Right_to_a_fair_hearing) is not breached.

The result is that the court has to hold a hearing — instead of deciding the case on the papers. Rob can effectively slow down and tamper with justice by claiming that he and Bob orally agreed to whatever.

*If* the oral modification was not allowed, Rob would not be able to stop the summary judgment by abusing his right to natural justice.